# Cómo hacer el manifest para todos los dispositivos android

Tags: android, google-play

He subido una *app* que se llama **Synergy** **for** **lol** y se puede descargar en la mayoría de dispositivos, pero en otros que también son actuales como el **LGE LG h-815** **( LG G4)** dice que no es compatible.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<supports-screens android:resizeable="true"
android:smallScreens="true"
android:normalScreens="true"
android:largeScreens="true"
android:xlargeScreens="true"
android:anyDensity="true"
/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/logo5"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".BdEquipo"
        android:parentActivityName=".Main2Activity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Equipo"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <!--
```

> ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to add Google Play services to your project for
>        App Indexing.  See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
>           -->

```
    <activity
        android:name=".Personalizar"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity android:name=".Sugerir" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Main2Activity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main2"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
    <activity android:name=".Guia" />
    <activity android:name=".Terminos"></activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 2):

**1)** Caracteristicas de hardware, definirlas como no requeridas, ya que alguno de los dispositivos podría no tener alguna de estas caracteristicas y provocaria que no pudiera ser instalada :

```
   <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.microphone"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.front"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.location"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.location.gps"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.wifi"
        android:required="false" />
```

**2)** definir una [versión mínima de API](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html) en el AndroidManifest.xml o build.gradle con el cual funcionaría tu aplicación, este API minimo esta determinado por los dispositivos que deseas tu aplicación funcione:

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
android:minSdkVersion="14"
```

Build.gradle:

```
android {
    ...
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
      ...
    }
```

**3)** Puedes omitir la versión `maxSdkVersion`, para permitir que funcione en todos los sistemas operativos, ya que `maxSdkVersion` determina en que versión máxima de sistema operativo la aplicación está diseñada para ejecutarse.

```
android {
    ...
    ...

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        ...
    }
```

De hecho esto comenta en la documentación oficial para los nuevos OS:

> **Advertencia**: No se recomienda declarar el atributo `maxSdkVersion`. En primer lugar,
>   no es necesario definir el atributo implementando el bloqueo de tu
>   aplicación en versiones nuevas de la plataforma de Android a medida
>   que se lancen. Gracias a su diseño, las versiones nuevas de la
>   plataforma son totalmente compatibles con versiones anteriores. Tu
>   aplicación debería funcionar correctamente en versiones nuevas, dado
>   que solo usa API estándares y sigue las prácticas recomendadas de
>   desarrollo. En segundo lugar, ten en cuenta que, en algunos casos, la
>   declaración del atributo puede ocasionar la eliminación de tu
>   aplicación de los dispositivos de los usuarios después de una
>   actualización del sistema a un nivel de API superior. La mayoría de
>   los dispositivos en los cuales probablemente se instale tu aplicación
>   recibirán actualizaciones de sistema periódicas de manera inalámbrica;
>   por eso, debes tener en cuenta su efecto en tu aplicación antes de
>   definir este atributo.

---

En algunos post he visto que agregan los tamaños de pantalla soportada por la aplicación pero en realidad si se agrega esto es para excluir ciertos dispositivos en los cuales no deseamos pueda ejecutarse nuestra aplicación.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html

Esto que defines en tu AndroidManifest.xml, podría ser causa de que en algunos dispositivos tu aplicación no sea soportada, de hecho no lo consideraría necesario agregar:

```
<supports-screens android:resizeable="true"
android:smallScreens="true"
android:normalScreens="true"
android:largeScreens="true"
android:xlargeScreens="true"
android:anyDensity="true"
/>
```

Comment: ¿No es obligatorio establecer una versión máxima?

Comment: Nop pero si defines android:minSdkVersion y android:maxSdkVersion es que defines únicamente entre esos valores funcione nuestra aplicación.

Comment: Sí, por supuesto si pones min y max sdk es para que funcione en esos valores. Sin embargo, pensaba que era obligatorio poner un máximo. Gracias por la aclaración :)