# Google play no me marca ningun dispotivo compatible para mi apk

Tags: android, android-studio, google-developers-console, google-play-console

Llevo 5 actualizaciones de mi app modificando el AndroidManifest.xml para haber si logro que en la ficha salga diferente a dispositivos compatible: 0 y no tengo éxito la [ficha de la app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.grupoenergeticos.gn).

Si me pudieran ayudar por favor.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

 < manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.grupoenergeticos.gn">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"  />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera2"
        android:required="true" />


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CLEAR_APP_CACHE" />


    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="24"  android:maxSdkVersion="25" />

    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true">
    </supports-screens>

    <compatible-screens  >
        <!-- all small size screens -->
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xxhdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xxxhdpi" />
        <!-- all normal size screens -->
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xxhdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xxxhdpi" />

        <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xxhdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xxxhdpi" />
    </compatible-screens>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Registro">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.grupoenergeticos.gn.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Login"
            android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".VerRegistro">

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.grupoenergeticos.gn.MainActivity" />
        </activity>

        <provider
            android:name=".GenericFileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.com.grupoenergeticos.gn.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
        </provider>
    </application> 
</manifest>
```

Gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
//    dexOptions{
//        javaMaxHeapSize "2048M"
//    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.grupoenergeticos.gn"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 5
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })


    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha9'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: No se si tengas un error aqui `< manifest` por el espacio

Comment: el espacio se lo agregue cuando lo subi a la pregunta

Comment: No estoy seguro pero `android.hardware.camera2` existe como caracteristica ? La api camera2, existe si no me equivoco como parte de android 5.0 en adelante, pero no creo que como característica. Eliminando ese `uses-feature` debería arreglar tu problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En realidad el mensaje indica que tu aplicación es incompatible con todos tus dispositivos, probablemente habrá otros en los que si se soporte, te doy 3 sugerencias para evitar tu aplicación aplique el filtro en algunos dispositivos.

- Primera sugerencia,

estas indicando que todos los dispositivos requieran esta característica de hardware:

```
 <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera2"
        android:required="true" />
```

¿es en realidad necesario? los dispositivos que no tengan este harware no podrán usar la aplicación por lo tanto no se mostraría para descarga desde Google Play, si no es indispensable para tu aplicación te recomiendo uses

```
android:required="false"
```

- Si tu aplicación prevee soportar todas las densidades y tamaños,

  esto no es necesario:

  ```
   <compatible-screens  >
          <!-- all small size screens -->
          <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
          <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
          <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
          <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
          <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xxhdpi" />
          <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xxxhdpi" />
          <!-- all normal size screens -->
          <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
          <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
          <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
          <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
          <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xxhdpi" />
          <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xxxhdpi" />

          <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
          <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
          <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
          <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
          <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xxhdpi" />
          <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xxxhdpi" />
      </compatible-screens>
  ```
- Estas definiendo que tu aplicación se soporta desde Android 4.1 (Jelly Bean) hasta Android 7.1.1 (Nougat),

¿tus dispositivos estan entre estas versiones de sistema operativo?

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="24"  
android:maxSdkVersion="25" />
```

En realidad esto puedes eliminarlo de tu archivo `AndroidManifest.xml` ya que la configuración en el `build.gradle` sobreescribe la del `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Comment: Muchas gracias solo poniendo el false en android:required="false"  fue compatible con los dispositvos.

Comment: Excelente Mario!, también es compatible para mis dispositivos, para más información te comparto esta otra respuesta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/38194/cómo-hacer-el-manifest-para-todos-los-dispositivos-android/38199#38199 saludos!